# Apache Spark: Loading HDFS parquet file causes SLF4J, BoneCP errors

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I run pyspark like this:

```
IPYTHON=1 pyspark --master 'local[32]' --driver-class-path '/opt/spark_jars/*'
```

Where `/opt/spark_jars/` contains BoneCP, SLF4J and various other jars that I want when working with spark. I can verify that they all end up on the spark driver's CLASSPATH successfully.

`spark-defaults.conf` also contains these lines:

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath       /opt/spark_connector/*
spark.driver.extraClassPath         /opt/spark_connector/*
```

However, this is what happens when I load a parquet file stored in HDFS:

```
In [1]: data = sqlCtx.load('/user/spark/parquet/data')
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
15/09/23 10:52:57 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
15/09/23 10:52:58 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
```

It's as though some separate Java process is being run that does not share the driver or executor CLASSPATH, but I can't find any documentation on it. The issue occurs with both Spark 1.3.1 and Spark 1.5.0.